Unrecognized feature: 'ch-ua-form-factor' : Permissions-Policy
I want to set Permission-Policy on my website, but getting
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ch-ua-form-factor'.
I am getting this error while browsing through the website on the console, I tried adding it to the header, but it started giving other errors. Checked multiple answers also on Stackoverflow but none worked.
Right now I am using only "Permissions-Policy: geolocation=(self)"
Also wanted to know what will be the effect if it is not solved

Im getting same error, any fix?
